# Compute mean across variable using R

Tags: r, data.table

I am encountering some troubles with creating a dataset that takes mean median 25 and 75th percentile across levels of a variable (in my case the variable is crisis_t in the dataset df1), below the code with my try. The problem is that the percentiles are not computed correctly and I cannot see why. Any idea ?

```
#what I have
country <- c("AT","AT","AT","AT","BE","BE","BE","BE","DE","DE","DE")
crisis_t  <- c(-1,0,1,2,-1,0,1,2,0,1,2)
value1  <- c(0.01,0.02,0.015,0.03,0.5,0.55,0.7,0.4,0.01,0.02,0.04)

df1 <- data.frame(country, crisis_t,value1)

#what I would like to obtain

crisis_t <- c(-1,0,1,2)
mean_t   <- c(0.255,0.193,0.245,0.156)
median_t <- c(0.255,0.02,0.02,0.04)
perc_25  <- c(NA,0.01,0.015,0.03)
perc_75  <- c(NA,0.55,0.7,0.4)

df2 <- data.frame(crisis_t, mean_t, median_t, perc_25, perc_75)

#my code does not compute correctly the 25th quantile
df1 <- as.data.table(df1)
df2_try <- data.table()
df2_try <- df1[,mean_t2:=mean(value1, na.rm=TRUE),by=.(crisis_t)]
df2_try <- df1[,median_t2:=median(value1, na.rm=TRUE),by=.(crisis_t)]
df2_try <- df1[,perc_25:=quantile(value1, probs=0.25),by=.(crisis_t)]
df2_try <- df1[,perc_75:=quantile(value1, probs=0.75),by=.(crisis_t)]

df2_try
```

Thanks for the help.

Edit: The actual dataset.

```
country       <- c("AT","AT","AT","AT","BE","BE","BE","BE","BE","BE","BE","DE","DE","DE")
crisis_AT_1   <- c(-1,0,1,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
crisis_BE_1   <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,NA,NA)
crisis_BE_2   <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,-2,NA,NA)
crisis_DE_1   <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-1,0)
value1        <- c(0.01,0.02,0.015,0.03,0.5,0.55,0.7,0.4,0.01,0.02,0.04,0.02,0.14,0.21)

df3 <- data.frame(country, crisis_AT_1,crisis_BE_1,crisis_BE_2,crisis_DE_1,value1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the [`quantile`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/quantile) function will use a continuous version of the quantiles. This means that if there isn't a number in the quantile you defined, it will estimate the number which should be in there, considering the empirical distribution given.

From your expected output, it seems that you want the **quantile type 2**, which will sample the quantiles over a discrete empirical distribution, but it will average at the middle of discontinuities. You can use it as follows:

```
df1 <- as.data.table(df1)
df2_try <- copy(df1)
df2_try[,mean_t2:=  mean(value1),by=.(crisis_t)]
df2_try[,median_t2:=quantile(value1, 0.50, type=2),by=.(crisis_t)]
df2_try[,perc_25:=  quantile(value1, 0.25, type=2),by=.(crisis_t)]
df2_try[,perc_75:=  quantile(value1, 0.75, type=2),by=.(crisis_t)]
```

However, this will not return the `NA` like you wanted, since the minimum value is in quantile 0, and the maximum value is in quantile 1, the quantiles 25% and 75% have indeed values associated with them. In spite of that, you can force that behavior if you really need it with an [`ifelse`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/ifelse).

By the way, you don't need to assign the `df2_try` after each modification. In `data.table`, the mutations you are doing are already inplace (they alter the object itself). So you can do it like I did in the example. I used the [`copy`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.8/topics/copy) function from `data.table` to have a copy of the original data.table `df1`, and the modified version `df2_try`.

Comment: I edited the question with some more difficulties given that I have different crisis for each country. Would it be possible to get the same result (mean across crisis) ?

Comment: I assume that you want the perc_25, mean, median and perc_75 for each country crisis_* group. With that in mind, what you need is to [gather (tidyverse)](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/gather.html) or [melt (data.table)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html) the crisis columns, and then do the same thing, but by the country, crisis_type and crisis_value columns,